# NodeJS send a PDF by Email using pdf creator

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, html-pdf

I'm new with NodeJS. I'm trying to generate a PDF from HTML and send it by email using nodemailer.

```
exports.testReqID = async (req, res, next) => {
    const ID = req.params.myID;

    const htmlData = `
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <h1>PDF Test. ID: ${ID}</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    `; // Just a test HTML

    pdf.create(htmlData).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
        let emailBody = "Test PDF";
        const email = new Email();
        const transporter = email.getTransporter();
        await transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'support@myemail.com', 
            to: 'me@myemail.com', 
            subject: "TEST", 
            html: emailBody, 
            attachments: {
                filename: 'test.pdf',
                contentType: 'application/pdf',   
                path: // How can I do it?
            }
        }); 
    });
};
```

The Email() class is just my settings for the nodemailer and it returns a transporter from `transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send it as a buffer. [docs](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments)

```
exports.testReqID = async (req, res, next) => {
    const ID = req.params.myID;

    const htmlData = `
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <h1>PDF Test. ID: ${ID}</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    `; // Just a test HTML

    pdf.create(htmlData).toBuffer(function(err, buffer){
        let emailBody = "Test PDF";
        const email = new Email();
        const transporter = email.getTransporter();
        await transporter.sendMail({
            from: 'support@myemail.com', 
            to: 'me@myemail.com', 
            subject: "TEST", 
            html: emailBody, 
            attachments: {
                filename: 'test.pdf',
                content: buffer',   
            }
        }); 
    });
};
```